# Custom view counts not updating correctly

Tags: filters, views

I'm trying to add some custom views/filters to the list of posts for a custom post type in the admin. However, the query that counts the number of posts is updating the number of posts for all filters at once, only if I am on one of those custom filters.

This is how I've set up the query that gets the number of posts:

```
add_action( 'views_edit-movies', array($this, 'custom_views') );
public function custom_views($views) {
    //$directors is a valid array returned from seperate function, removed for clarity
    foreach ($directors as $key => $value) {
        $director = $value;
        $query = array(
           'post_type' => 'movies',
           'meta_key' => 'director',
           'meta_value' => $director
        );
        $result = new WP_Query($query);

        $class = ($wp_query->query_vars['meta_value'] == $director) ? ' class="current"' : '';
        $views["$director"] = sprintf(__('<a href="%s"'. $class .'>' . $director . ' <span class="count">(%d)</span></a>'),
        admin_url('edit.php?&post_type=movies&director='.$director),
        $result->found_posts);
    }//end foreach
}
```

This works fine if I am on the "All", "Published", or "Trash" default views, and each director filter has the correct number of posts on those views. When I then click on a director, all other directors have the same number of posts as the one as I am currently on.

Is this because I'm assigning the views within a foreach loop, based on a variable? Or because I'm changing the query to display the view with the code below?

Here is the code that actually displays the views:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array($this, 'filters') );
public function filters($query)
{
    if ( isset($_GET['director']) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'director' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', $_GET['director'] );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: You should post this as an answer. You might even score yourself some reputation points that are vital to use more functionality on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the `$query->set` in the filter function was updating the main query used to count the number of posts. Likely due to the order in which they were called. I tried to flush and run a new `wp_query` but what ultimately worked best was the function below that uses a custom query.

```
public function count($director)
{ 
 $num = $this->wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $this->wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'directory' AND meta_value = '".$director."'"); 
 return count($num); 
}
```